# Como puedo enviar una notificacion con javascript sin un contexto seguro (sin https)

Tags: javascript, html, http, push-notification, https

Basicamente la función que hice para enviar notificaciones esta dentro de una variable que es un objeto (json), por eso tiene esa estructura. La funcion DeleteNotify lo que hace es borrar la notificación de la base de datos con un fetch, estoy usando flask, javascript y MongoDB.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que la función pueda enviar notificaciones en entornos no seguros o con http?

```javascript
EnviarNotificacion: function(titulo, content, icon, idnotify) {
        Notification.requestPermission().then(function (perm) {
            if (perm == 'granted') {
                const notification = new Notification(titulo, {
                    body: content,
                    icon: icon,
                    // tag: 'Mision asignada',
                });
                notification.addEventListener('show', function() {
                    DeleteNotify('NODATA', idnotify);
                });
            }
        })
    },
```